# ObservableCollection Remove() not firing to Visibility binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a strange issue with my WPF project. I have a `ObservableCollection<T>` bound to a `ListBox`. When I add and remove items, the binding works and the list displays the correct results.

The issue I have, is I'm also binding this same property to another XAML control, but it doesn't trigger the converter when I remove an item from the list. It works when I add items.

The relevant XAML is

```
<view:WelcomeView Visibility="{Binding Steps, Converter={StaticResource CollapseIfZero}}"/>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Steps}" />
```

And the converter is

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    var col = value as ICollection;
    return col.Count == 0 ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

I have a break point in the converter. When a new item is added, the break point is hit. When an existing item is removed, the break point is not hit.

Does WPF do something magical with the `ListBox` which I'm not aware of (which has led to this unexpected behavior)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ObservableCollection implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `ListBox` (and other `ItemsControl`s) listens when collection was modified.

`Steps` property itself doesn't change, it is the same ObservableCollection.

WelcomeView.Visibility is bound to `Steps`, and doesn't update because *property value didn't change*, it keeps the same object reference.

try create binding to `Steps.Count` property (converter should be modified to use `int value`)

```
<view:WelcomeView Visibility="{Binding Steps.Count, Converter={StaticResource CollapseIfZeroCount}}"/>
```

or

there is `bool HasItems` property in `ItemsControl`. I would make a binding with `ElementName` and `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`

```
<view:WelcomeView "{Binding ElementName=Lst, Path=HasItems, Converter={StaticResource Bool2Visibility}}"/>
<ListBox Name="Lst" ItemsSource="{Binding Steps}" />
```

Comment: So would another option is to have my WelcomeView subscribe to `INotifyCollectionChanged` ?

Comment: @Dave, i think, yes it is possible, but requires more efforts. you need to make sure that WelcomeView unsubscribes when necessary

Comment: You could also fire the OnPropertyChanged("Steps"); manually after removing an item in your viewmodel (as simple work around).

Comment: @ASh: I agree that this is just a workaround and the best way (Binding to Steps.Count seems better). In my tests, notifying the ObservableCollection Steps after removing items did work. I had the addition {Binding Steps, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged} and using the Cliburn.Micro Framework (with NotifyOfPropertyChange). Maybe thats the difference.

Comment: @Fabian, i found my bug with `OnPropertyChanged("Steps")`, thanks for idea. i used DataGrid for my tests, where user can select row and press Delete to remove it. calling `OnPropertyChanged("Steps")` is not trivial is this case